# Sql goup by status

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a query like this

```
select U.Name, Edatetime,IOType from Mx_ACSEventTrn
left join Mx_UserMst U on Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=U.UserID
 where Edatetime between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-30 23:59:59'
```

my result is

```
 Name                 date                     status
Husam Hajawi    2019-10-30 07:29:13.000         0
Marjune Deigo Pascua    2019-10-30 07:32:34.000 1
```

status 0 means in punch and status 1 means out punch.so i want to get result like this:

my result is

```
  Name                    In                        OUT                   
    Husam Hajawi           2019-10-30 07:29:13.000          
    Marjune Deigo Pascua    2019-10-30 07:32:34.000   2019-10-30 08:32:34.000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using conditional aggregation

```
select U.Name, 
       min(case when status=0 then Edatetime end) as in,
       max(case when status=1 then Edatetime end) as out
from Mx_ACSEventTrn
left join Mx_UserMst U on Mx_ACSEventTrn.UsrRefcode=U.UserID
where Edatetime between '2019-10-30 00:00:00' and '2019-10-30 23:59:59' 
group by U.Name
```

Comment: Instead of using this datetime between i can use any other simple logic?

Comment: @user3262364, yes you can use any logic

Comment: now i am adding 00:00:00 and 23:59:59. instead of this i can add any cast operator

Comment: @user3262364, yes you can use cast operator

Comment: can you show me how i can use cast operator. thanks

Comment: when i use left join i got some null, instead of this i am using inner join